# Как собрать nginx с модулем http_ssi_module?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssi

Всем привет! Использую nginx 1.10.3 на Debian 9. В один прекрасный момент мне понадобились SSI, но либо они не фурычат из коробки, либо я что-то делаю не так. К примеру есть такие файлики:

```
название: 1.htm 
содержимое: test

название 2.htm
содержимое: <!--#include file="1.htm" -->
```

Запрашиваю у nginx 2.htm, приходит ответ `<!--#include file="1.htm" -->`, вместо ожидаемого test. Конфига nginx:

```
location / {
   ssi on;
}
```

Предположил, что модуль ssi не установлен. На сайте дебиана указано:

```
Пакет: nginx-light[|| full || extras] (1.10.3-1+deb9u1)
OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: ... SSI ...
```

Означает ли это, что модуль включен в поставку nginx и его надо как то активировать, или просто не включен, я не знаю. Если не включен, нужно пересобирать nginx. Пробую собрать [вот по этой статье](https://firstwiki.ru/index.php/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_nginx_%D0%B2_Linux_(Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS)), в команду ./configure в конец добавляю --with-http_ssi_module и получаю ошибку

./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_ssi_module".

Пробую чуть по-другому модуль прописать, но не помогает:

```
./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_ssi_filter_module"
./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_ssi_module=dynamic"
```

Вопрос: где я, что я делаю не так?

Comment: чтобы узнать, какие модули включены при сборке, запустите программу *nginx* с опцией `-V`

Comment: Это я делал, нету модуля ssi в списке.

Comment: судя по комментариям в исходниках он входит в состав неких «базовых модулей» и собирается по умолчанию. сборку можно отключить отключить отдельной опцией (`--without-bla-bla-ssi-bla-bla`). раз её нет в выводе после запуска с опцией `-V`, значит не отключена.